# Github configuration id_rsa password

Tags: github, passwords

For the github configuration, I have completed the steps of

1.) creating new SSH keys
2.) entering my id_rsa.pub key and thus adding the key

But during the testing stage of testing, after I entered

***user$ ssh -T git@github.com***

A new window (outside the terminal) opens up asking : **Enter your password for  "id_rsa"**. *Where can I find this password*. FYI, I am using a Mac OS 10.5.8

Even after I entered:

***user$ ssh -vT git@github.com***

The same new window opens up asking for the "id_rsa" password.

Please help.

Comment: The password is the one you've entered in step 1, "creating new SSH keys".

Answer (score 0):

While creating your ssh key in step 1), make sure to enter no passphrase for it. Otherwise the setup will be more complicated as you need to use something like ssh-agent to enter the password automatically for you.